# Iron Router Use "/" Route for Dynamic Posts? "/my-post-here" (Shorter URLs)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to get this to work with iron router? Something like a rewrite rule.

I have posts slugs I'm trying to show as `/my-post-title` instead of `/posts/my-post-title` the problem is that `/` route is a home page and I also have many other routes such as `/log-in` etc... so I can't really figure out a way to accomplish this anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could have all other routes above `'/:myPostTitle'` route, since IronRouter checks matching routes in order.

For example:

```
this.route('/logIn');
this.route('/:myPostTitle');
```

If the route matches logIn, the user goes to logIn, otherwise the next route is checked for a match and the user will be sent to the myPostTitle route if it's a match.

Comment: @Elizezer this sounds perfect I will have to test and report back :)

Comment: Having hard time making that route the last one because I got few routes from packages...

Comment: @Elizezer any idea on how to force last order? I think it's actually not so easy if even possible. Iron Router doesn't provide the option.

Comment: You're right. If packages are adding routes, I don't know how you could force the order. You can do a check in myposttitle to see if the route matches another route from a package and then redirect if it does and otherwise render the page. Could become a bit of a mess, but don't know if there's a more elegant solution. You could just change the route to /p/:postTitle or /post/:postTitle or even /post/:id. That's what I'd do. There are packages that will help you if you want to use postTitle